# Code to get all ports used by ASP.NET Development Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, port

In my solution I have 5 websites that run locally on Visual Studios `ASP.NET Development Server`.

Is there some code (C# or VB.NET) in the code behind of one of those sites that can find all the ports used by the ASP.NET Development server?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Web Administration API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration%28VS.90%29.aspx), you will need to look especially at the [Site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.site%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) object.

Answer (score 0):

try. [Request.Url.Port](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.url.aspx)

```
Request.Url.Port // will give the port of the server.
```

Comment: That will only give you the port of the site, usually 80.